# power shell replace double quotation marks

Tags: powershell

I am having a problem trying to replace a string in a very big file (about 8gb). For that im using powershell.
The string im trying to replace is the following:

### '"'||ROW_ID||'","'||SUBSTR(P.ADDR_NAME,INSTR(P.ADDR_NAME,'')+1)||'"'

(As a comment, there is an "intro", then the string is af it seen)
and i want to replace it with the following:
''
(As a comment, is with nothing)

The Shell im using at the moment, is the following:

```
$InFile = 'foo.txt'
$OutFile = 'foo2.txt'

filter filter replace-chars { $_ -replace '                                                       

'"'||ROW_ID||'","'||SUBSTR(P.ADDR_NAME,INSTR(P.ADDR_NAME,'')+1)||'"'            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------','' }


if (test-path $OutFile)
 { Clear-Content $OutFile }

Get-Content $InFile -ReadCount 1000 | 
 replace-chars  | 
 Add-Content $OutFile
```

And I receive the following error:

> "
>   + filter filter replace-chars { $_ -replace '
>   +              ~ Missing function body in function declaration. At F:\Reporte_medios_de_contacto_PROD\test.ps1:7 char:2
>   + '"'||ROW_ID||'","'||SUBSTR(P.ADDR_NAME,INSTR(P.ADDR_NAME,'')+1)||'"'
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Unexpected token '"'||ROW_ID||'"' in expression or statement. At F:\Reporte_medios_de_contacto_PROD\test.ps1:7 char:68
>   + '"'||ROW_ID||'","'||SUBSTR(P.ADDR_NAME,INSTR(P.ADDR_NAME,'')+1)||'"'
>   +                                                                    ~ Unexpected token ''
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------'' in expression or statement.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingFunctionBody "

Comment: Solved using a powerfull computer and EmEditor. Thanks for the really helpful and comprehensive help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using a powerfull computer (16 gb ram) and EmEditor.

Answer (score 0):

```
(Get-Content c:/YourFile.txt) -replace 'What you want to remove', 'what you ` 
want to replace it with' | Set-Content c:/YourFile.txt
```

For example, getting rid of quotation marks alone do this:

```
(Get-Content c:/YourFile.txt) -replace '"', '' | Set-Content c:/YourFile.txt
```